# How do I manually trigger a jPicker dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jpicker

I have three jPicker binded to hidden inputs. They work fine.
My problem is that I would like to open their dialogs also by clicking on a `div` or `<a>` set somewhere else.
I can't figure out how to achieve this result.
I tried with `$('#myElement').jPicker()`, `$('#myElement').jPicker("show")`, `$('#myElement').jPicker().show()` but nothing worked so far.
I know I'm doing something wrong and I think there must be a way to invoke the same dialog from different anchors.
I also need it to work in different situations, like, eg., as a callback when an animation completes.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code where I set up the jPicker dialog:

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#c_d_item_color1').jPicker(
    {
        window:{position:{x:'screenCenter',y:'screenCenter'}}
    },
    function(color, context) {
        var all = color.val('all');
        var temp = 'nocolor';
        if (all !== null) {
            temp = '#' + all.hex;
        }
        worker_changeColorByJPicker(temp, 1);
     }            
     )
 );
```

So jPicker is set on `#c_d_item_color1` and I need this dialog to be triggered by some other event, like a confirm, callback or another anchor.

This is the current input where the jPicker is binded:

```
<input class="cf-jpicker" type="hidden" id="c_d_item_color1" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Try with `document.ready(function()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myElement').jPicker("show");//I think it would work without the "show" parameter
});
```

To make it append on click event try

```
$("#my_div").click(function(){
    $(this).jPicker("show");
})
```

Comment: That's not the problem. I would also like to have it triggered by a different event, like in an animation callback.

Comment: Your question say that you want to open jPicker on a `<div>` or `<a>` tag. Im I right ?

Comment: Yes, edited it to be more complete. Thanks for your answer anyway. I need it to work on any event indeed, like a callback or after a confirm dialog.

Comment: You want to open the jPicker set to an hidden input when you click on a div that is somewhere  in the page ? Is that your question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#MyElement")
  .button()
  .click(function() {
    $( "#Jpicker_ID" ).jPicker("open");
  });
```

Comment: not working, it adds a jPicker icon next to the one that already exists.